# Print html table with fixed header

Tags: html, pdf

The print table works fine when I have less row in the header appear on all page header section(`<thead></thead>`) but when I add a new row in the header, it shows only on first-page, not other pages. Take a look at my table [Table Record And Header before inserting new row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeSq8.png)

[Table Print preview after inserting a new row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgEm2.png)

> This Code works fine but when we a row in "thead" it cause the problem

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" border="1" width="100%" style="font-size:10px; font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="12">
            <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" ">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <img id="logo" style="height:100px;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeSq8.png" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div style="font-size: 30px; text-transform: uppercase;text-align: center;">
                            Company CONTAINER LINES PVT.LTD.
                        </div>
                        <div style="text-align:center; font-size:12px;">
                            <div style="text-transform:uppercase">203, RAMPRATAP HOUSE, 4, L.S.C. KALKAJI, NEW DELHI-11009</div>
                            <div>Tel: +91-11-65411167 / +91-11-6511168, E-Mail- acc.del@copanygroup.net</div>
                            <div>CIN : U74990DL2014PTC272551</div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center" width="25%">Billing State</td>
        <td colspan="3" align="center" width="25%">DELHI</td>
        <td colspan="3" align="center" width="25%">Code</td>
        <td colspan="3" align="center" width="25%">07</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" width="50%" align="center">PAN NO: AACCL7528B</td>
        <td colspan="6" width="50%" align="center">GSTIN: 07AACCL7528B1ZQ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="12" align="center" style="background-color:#ddd; font-size:25px;text-transform:uppercase;"><span>proforma Invoice</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="12" align="center"><em>THIS IS NOT FOR GST TAX PURPOSE</em></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1" align="center" width="5%">SNo</td>
        <td colspan="3" align="center">Product Description  </td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">HSN Code</td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">Qty</td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">Rate</td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">Ex-Rate</td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">Taxable Value</td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">
            <span>IGST %</span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center">
            <span>IGST Amt</span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center" width="7%">Total</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">1</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">2</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">3</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">4</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">5</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">6</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">7</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">8</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">9</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">10</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">11</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">12</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">13</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">14</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">15</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">16</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">17</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">18</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">19</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">20</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">21</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">22</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">23</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">24</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">25</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">26</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">27</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">28</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">29</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">30</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">31</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">32</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">33</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">34</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">35</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">36</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">37</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">38</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">39</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">40</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">41</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">42</td>
            <td colspan="3">CONTAINER CLEANING CHARGES</td>
            <td align="right">996711</td>
            <td align="right">4.00</td>
            <td align="right">400.00</td>
            <td align="right">0.00</td>
            <td align="right">1600.00</td>
                <td align="right">18.00</td>
                <td align="right">288.00</td>
            <td align="right">1888.00</td>
        </tr>
    <tr style="background-color:#ddd">
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="3"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">67200.00</td>
            <th></th>
            <td align="right">12096.00</td>
        <td align="right" style="width:100px">79296.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" rowspan="2" style="font-size:20px;background-color:#ddd;" align="center">Total</td>
        <td colspan="5">Total Amount Before Tax</td>
        <td colspan="1" align="right">67200.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            Add:
                <span>IGST</span>
        </td>
        <td colspan="1" align="right">12096.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" align="center">Total Invoice Amount in Words</td>
        <td colspan="5">Total Amount After Tax</td>
        <td colspan="1" align="right">79296.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" rowspan="2">
            USD: seventy-nine thousand two hundred and ninety-six
        </td>
        <td colspan="5">Round Off</td>
        <td colspan="1" align="right">

            0.00
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">TOTAL PAYABLE</td>
        <td colspan="1" align="right">79296.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">Wire Details</td>
        <td colspan="5">AXISPL</td>
        <td colspan="6" rowspan="4" align="center">
            <div>Certified that the perticulars given above are true and correct</div>
            <div style="font-size:14px">For Company CONTAINER LINES PVT.LTD.</div>
            <div style="font-size:14px; padding-top:15px">Authorised Signatory</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">A/C #</td>
        <td colspan="5">911020040981267</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">Bank IFSC</td>
        <td colspan="5">UTIB0000357</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">Address</td>
        <td colspan="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="12">
            <div>
                -> All payment should be drawn in favour of "Company CONTAINER LINES PVT.LTD.".<br />
                -> Dispute if any shall be subject to be jurisdication of delhi courts only.<br />
                -> We reserve the right to charge interest at 2.5%/month of all bills overdue for more than 15 days without prejudice.<br />
                -> No claim and/or discrepency if any shall be considered inless brought to the notice of the of the company in writhing three (03) days of receipts of bill.<br />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Share your code here..

Answer (score 0):

https://www.dhirajsharma.com/print_table.html

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function()
                    {
                        var printHeader = $('#print-header-wrapper').html();
                        var div_pageBreaker = '<div style="page-break-before:always;"></div>';
                        var per_page = 25;
                        $('#table_data').each(function(index, element)
                        {
                            //how many pages of rows have we got?
                            var pages = Math.ceil($('tbody tr').length / per_page);

                            //if we only have one page no more
                            if (pages == 1) {
                                return;
                            }
                            //get the table we're splutting
                            var table_to_split = $(element);

                            var current_page   = 1;
                            //loop through each of our pages
                            for (current_page = 1; current_page <= pages; current_page++) 
                            {
                                //make a new copy of the table
                                var cloned_table = table_to_split.clone();
                                //remove rows on later pages
                                $('tbody tr', table_to_split).each(function(loop, row_element) {
                                    //if we've reached our max
                                    if (loop >= per_page) {
                                        //get rid of the row
                                        $(row_element).remove();
                                    }
                                });

                                //loop through the other copy
                                $('tbody tr', cloned_table).each(function(loop, row_element) {
                                    //if we are before our current page
                                    if (loop < per_page) {
                                        //remove that one
                                        $(row_element).remove();
                                    }
                                });

                                //insert the other table afdter the copy
                                if (current_page < pages) {
                                    $(div_pageBreaker).appendTo('#lastDataTable');
                                    $(printHeader).appendTo('#lastDataTable');
                                    $(cloned_table).appendTo('#lastDataTable');
                                }

                                //make a break
                                table_to_split = cloned_table;
                            }
                        });
                    });
```

```css
@media print{
                        table { page-break-after:auto;}
                        tr    { page-break-inside:avoid;}
                        td    { page-break-inside:auto;}
                        thead { display:table-header-group }

                        .row-fluid [class*="span"] {
                          min-height: 20px;
                        }
                    }

                    @page { 
                        margin-top: 1cm;
                        margin-right: 1cm;
                        margin-bottom:2cm;
                        margin-left: 2cm;';
                        size:portrait;
                        /*
                        size:landscape;
                        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
                        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
                        */

                    };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="print-header-wrapper">
                    <div class="row-fluid">HEADER TITLE 1</div>
                    <div class="row-fluid">HEADER TITLE 2</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid" id="print-body-wrapper">
                    <table class="table" id="table_data">
                        <thead>
                            <tr><th>TH 1</th><th>TH 2</th></tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                            <tr><td>TD 1</td><td>TD 2</td></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div id="lastDataTable"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Each row content, not similar mean some content complete in one line but some of them cover more than one line so limiting or fixing the number of rows cause the problem. Well...thanks for trying...Sharma JI